# Separating axis test in 4D and higher dimensions for simplex faces

Tags: geometry, collision-detection

I am trying to determine if two simplices in a simplicial complex intersect in an appropriate manner, i.e. they intersect in a single vertex, edge or face-to-face.

In order to achieve that I try to see if faces of two simplices intersect appropriately. I try to use the separating axis test to check if faces, i.e., (n-1)-simplices, of the n-simplex are separable by a hyperplane in n-D space. For example, I want to check if two tetrahedra (3-simplices) intersect in 4D.

I tried to generalize an explanation in ["Intersection of Convex Objects: The Method of Separating Axes"](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf) by David Eberly, section "Separation of Convex Polygons in 3D" , as this deals with separation of (n-1) simplices in n-D space. I could not understand how to construct all potential separating axis directions, suggested there.

Choices for potential axes are:

1. Normal to a face;
2. Direction perpendicular to both the face normal and "edge" (in 4D we could call a triange face of a tetrahedron such an "edge");
3. Cross product of a pair edges from different faces should be computed.

I could not understand how to generalize cross products of edges to 4 dimensions. One need at least 3 vectors (not a pair of them) to simulate cross product computation in 4D, as presented [here](http://ef.gy/linear-algebra%3anormal-vectors-in-higher-dimensional-spaces).

Could anyone suggest how it would be best to choose potential separating axis directions in 4D and higher?

Also, if I am pursuing a wrong line of thinking about the correct positioning of simplices, please advise how better to check this.